# How to sum items in foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, sum

```
foreach ($dives_file as $dives) {
    $type = explode(",", $dives);
    $divetype = $type[1];
    $duration = $type[2];
    $depth = $type[3];
}
```

How can I get the sum of all the `$duration` numbers?

Comment: Initialize a variable and then just add the values in the foreach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code to the next:

```
$duration = 0;

    foreach ($dives_file as $dives) 
    {
       $type = explode(",", $dives);
       $divetype = $type[1];
       $duration += $type[2];
       $depth = $type[3]; 
    }
```

Comment: For reference, see [Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), specifically "combined operators".